# How do I make a series of radio buttons greyed out until a source one is clicked while still making the group of radio buttons function as normal?

Tags: pdf, interactive, acrobat, adobe-indesign

Note: there is a text field within these radio buttons as well. My form is quite complex and I have never used scripts before. How do I make this work? See below...

This first photo shows how the buttons should look when the left-most one is not selected.

[image]

The second photo is what it would look like once the left button is selected. Any or all of the options can be selected. An the "other" field at the bottom needs to function as a space where users can add content if they wish to.

[image]

Knowing all of this, how do I proceed?

Comment: I should also mention that I have several of these situations in the same 2-page form. Ugh!

Comment: Without knowing Acrobat Javascript fairly well, your task is going to be difficult. Because radio buttons in PDF don't have labels, the text next to the radio buttons will also need to be created as text fields. So for each radio button label pair, you'll need two fields whose "enabled" property and textColor will be dependent on the value of the "important reminders" field. I suggest you start be learning a how Acrobat JavaScript differs from Browser JavaScript and then proceed.